# How can I Change the layout of UICollectionView for both grid and list in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that is using grid layout currently I have two cells in a row.

I want to give the user a choice to switch between grid and list layout similar like table view.

How can I proceed for the same.

Comment: I do not know why do users mark answers negative without even mentioning why it is not worth asking.

Answer (score 0):

use `segmentcontroller` with `uicollectionviewcontroller` and `uitableviewcontroller`. then `implement delegate methods and datasource methods` for both. then hide one `view controller` `tableview` or `collectionview`. then implement the `action` for `segment controller`.

when `segment index == 0` show `collectionview` else show `tableview`. hope this will help to you.

or else you can use same `uicollectionveiw` with `sections`.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfItemsInSection` shoud return `0` that means there is one item(row) per section. You consider this as list view. you can manage size or look and feel accordingly.

`numberOfItemsInSection` returns `2` or more whatever number of items you want in your section that means it is grid view.

You have to managa datasource methods accordingly. You should have to set some flag that keep status that user have selected the list or grid.

according to that status you can manage your datasource or delegate.

Second approach :

Use `collection view` for `grid representation` and `tableview` for `list representation` and just `show and hide` one of them according to user's choice as a result of grid or list.

Comment: Do you know ways to play with collection view flow layout